# How to disable auto-hide taskbar in full screen slide show mode in PowerPoint?

Tags: powerpoint, slideshow, taskbar

While presenting in full screen slide show mode in PowerPoint, taskbar auto hide after 2-3 seconds.
Can we set it permanently or disable it so that taskbar will not hide? Because it's annoying while you have to switch screens.
Help me.
Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it, just open Power Point and go `File (upper left corner) -> Options (bottom left corner) -> Advanced -> Uncheck 'Show popup toolbar'`

[image]

You can also handle it when you are in full screen presentation mode, but you need to do it every time when you present something.

[image]

Comment: This will hide the toolbar but i want to view taskbar all the time so that i can switch between screens.